# I have text file with a 2D matrix in it. How do turn this into a grey scale image in python?

Tags: python

I'm fairly new with python so I'm not really sure where to start. All I have done is I imported the text file to python. I was suggested to use matshow.py but I don't know how I would use the text file to create the actual image.

Comment: You mean the matshow.py which is demonstrated [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/matshow.html) as an example?

Comment: Yes except I don't know how to use the the matrix I have to create an image like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you can contrive to get your text file into a `numpy` array then this kind of code will work. Just research, or ask another question, about reading a text file into a `numpy` array.

```
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pic = np.zeros((100,100), dtype=np.int8)
>>> image = Image.fromarray(pic)
>>> image.show()
```

Here I import the `Image` class from the `PIL` library. Then I create a 100x100  array of zeroes in `pic` using `numpy`. I use a method from `Image` to make this into an `Image` object and then display the (utterly uninteresting, completely black) result.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to achieve, your point isn't clear.

if you are trying to draw an image using a matrix.

you will need to look into PIL.

Here is the [link](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) to download the library and here is the [link](https://www.google.com.eg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt_8n2_qnUAhVMsBQKHRuIBQsQFghAMAM&url=http%3A%2F%2Feffbot.org%2Fimagingbook%2Fpil-index.htm&usg=AFQjCNHZ0l9SH1ihB9FscnVBXORt4ZbkQQ) for the documentations.

Comment: Yes I am trying to draw an image with the matrix I was given. I will look into this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Matrix = loadtxt(filename)
imshow(Matrix)
```

These functions come from the `numpy` and `matplotlib` libraries, respectivelly.